# Pointers confusion in C

Tags: c, pointers, character

i'm new to programming in C, and I've been thinking about this problem for quite some time now:

```
char* name;
scanf("%s", name);
```

Why doesn't this work? For example, if I type in "Hello", the program just gives me an error.
But isn't the above code the exact same thing as this?

```
char* name = "Hello";
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
char* name;
```

declares a pointer but doesn't initialise it to point to memory you have allocated.  Attempts to write to it using `scanf` result in undefined behaviour and may well crash.

```
char* name = "Hello";
```

declares a pointer and initialises it to point to a string literal.  String literals may be stored in read-only memory so you should think of this as having type `const char*`.

So, if you want to assign a string at run-time, neither of these approaches would work.  You would instead have to allocate memory for a `char` array then use `scanf` (or `fgets`, `readline`, etc.) to write a string to that memory

```
char name[20];
scanf("%19s", name);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
If you don't know the size of array before runtime , maybe you need a malloc
char* name = malloc(N); // you should initialize just N before use it.
scanf("%s", name);// It can work now , however it may case a overflow if you type too mach ,more than N-1
```

Or you can use

```
int n; 
if(( n = read(STDIN_FILENO,name,N)) <0)
{printf("read error"); return -1;}
name[n]  = 0;
```

Or

```
fgets(name,N,stdin) ;
```

Beside, after you used it, remeber free the memory

```
free(name);
```

Comment: If you're going to recommend use of `malloc`, it'd be good to also show that `free` needs to be called later.

Comment: You also don't want to have just `scanf("%s")` because of the overflow  vulnerabilities

Comment: And, as the OP indicates that he/she is new to programming in C, you might add a brief explanation of what it actually means to "allocate memory".

Comment: @DennisMeng ok , give me 1 min.

Comment: @cli_hlt give me 1 min.